# If "learning styles" are bunk, then what is the most effective form of learning?

Tags: learning, psychology

I have read research claiming the idea of multiple styles of learning does not hold up. If so, what does the research say is the best form of learning/teaching?

Comment: Which research? What exactly is "the idea of multiple styles of learning"? Express yourself clearly.

Comment: Too broad.  You are asking for a summary of the entire field of education.

Comment: I agree with Nate.  I think I know what you're getting at, as I have (also) heard that there are studies which report statistically insignificant or very minor gains from focusing on "visual learning" versus "auditory learning" versus "hands-on learning" etc. and mixtures thereof.  But your question would be improved by including references, clarification of terms, and/or what school level to focus on if any.  Possibly this would be better suited on another SE.  We have a Math Educators SE, if you were mostly interested in how this sort of question pertains to mathematics, for example.

Comment: All theories are criticized by someone. The real object should be to know the strengths and weaknesses of the theories in your field. Knowing this allows you to make appropriate decisions based on whatever it is you are trying to do.

There is no single best way to learn. There are a plethora of different ways. What is best depends on the needs of the students which vary from class to class.

Comment: @DarrinThomas: Not all theories are created equal. Some theories are flat-out false, and we should endeavor to know which ones they are.

Comment: That's why you examine the strengths and the weaknesses. Theories that are completely wrong are normally not even generally accepted or even discussed except to teach students how the person was wrong.

Comment: @DarrinThomas: Disagree. See, e.g., Ioannidis, "Why Most Published Research Findings Are False".

Comment: @Daniel: Off course we disagree because we each have our own "theory" of what is an appropriate comment for this question.

Answer (score 8):

Recent eagle's-eye overview of best-practice study methods: Dunlosky, John, et al. "What works, what doesn't." *Scientific American Mind* 24.4 (2013): 46-53.

Gold star winners:

- **Self-testing.** That is: doing homework exercises and checking the answers.
- **Distributed practice.** Studying regularly in batches over time (not cramming).

Runners-up (mixed evidence):

- **Elaborative interrogation.**
- **Self-explanation.**
- **Interleaved practice.** ("Mixed practice")

What doesn't work:

- **Highlighting.**
- **Rereading.**
- **Summarization, keyword mnemonics, and imagery for text learning.**

Comment: Here's a [copy of the article](http://tguilfoyle.cmswiki.wikispaces.net/file/view/What_works,_What_doesn't.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Multimodal Learning**
as per the article *Multimedia design: the effects of relating multimodal information*, M. Dubois and I. Vial

> A statistically significant effect was observed on word memorisation
>   in the different information presentation modes, suggesting better
>   processing when there is co-referencing of the different sources,
>   especially when the encoding and tests modes are the same.

In general, people learn better when the material is presented from multiple types of media: text, audio, video, etc.

The article is linked here:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2729.2000.00127.x/abstract